# Docker run doesn't save file created by script

Tags: docker

I have following Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6
MAINTAINER "Alexey Nikitin"


RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install tensorflow
RUN pip install numpy pandas 
RUN pip install keras --no-deps

RUN ["mkdir", "/tmp/data"]
RUN ["mkdir", "/var/log/result"]
RUN ["mkdir", "/model"]


ADD ./data /tmp/data
ADD ./model /model

WORKDIR /model
CMD ["python", "predict.py"]
```

The result of predict.py is text file saved in the same directory.
After running `docker run -it toxic` I see file executing. But when I enter container, I don't see created file.

[image]

How can I run container and save file created by script?

Answer (score 2):

From what i understood, your script runs some logic and then finishes. As soon as your script is finished, Docker container exits and all data that was created is deleted. To persist this data you need to use [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/), for example:

```
docker run -it -v $(pwd):/model toxic
```

In that case, generated file will be stored in your current directory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How can I see created file? It's created at my machine or inside container?

Comment: @AlexNikitin It will be persisted in directory on your machine.

Comment: Is there any way to store created file in container and then enter it and see it there?

Comment: @AlexNikitin Do you need to reuse that file in future executions? If so, using volumes will solve that problem for you -- that file will be available in container if you run it next time with same local directory bound to container.

Answer (score 2):

From `man docker-run`:

> DESCRIPTION
> Run a process in a new container. docker run starts a process with its own file system, its own networking, and its own isolated
> process tree.

You first `docker run` invocation creates the file in the filesystem of a container. The second invocation runs as a different container, with its own filesystem.
In other words, files in the filesystem of a container are not to be considered persistent.

`Volumes` are the way you achieve persistency.

In your case, I would use:

```
docker run -v <path>:/model -it toxic
```

Now even if the containers are gone, the content of `/model` inside the container is mapped to `<path>` in your host machine.

There are more ways in which you can use volumes, please refer to https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Not related, but just to add: I almost always prefer to add `--rm` to `docker run`. It removes the container when `run` has finished. Otherwise you end up with many ended containers that you need to remove manually at some point.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How can I see created file? It's created at my machine or inside container?

Comment: The file will be in `<path>`, in your machine. At the same time, it will be available in your container every time you run it with the same volume mapping.